# How to override Automatic column hiding in responsive jquery Datatable plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I want to have horizontal scrolling in the jquery datatable responsive web design.
But when i use the responsive plugin for datatable the ScrollX doesnot work.

I read this on thier [page](https://www.datatables.net/blog/2014-07-16):

**Columns that that don't fit into the available area are removed automatically**

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.7/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

You can see example [here](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/auto.html).

Resize the window to see that columns are automatically hiding but i want to place a scroll if columns overflow the screen size.

i tried fixing it with Css but no use.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use dataTables.responsive.min.js, the normal jquery.dataTables.min.js is enough if you just want to scroll. you can do it like this:

```
$("#yourTable").DataTable({
    "scrollY": 200,
    "scrollX": true
});
```

Check out the documentation as well: https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX

Hope that helps

Comment: I want to make datatable responsive too so that it expand and shrink on resizing the window

Comment: I don't think you can have both mate.

Comment: Thanks, Removing responsive.min worked for me !!